# Reading data from Excel (SQL Import List)

Tags: mysql, sql, datagrip

```
TABLE1
STUDENTID COURSE INSTRUCTOR YEAR SCORE GRADE
```

I have TABLE1 with the structure above for a whole school district. Also I have EXCEL file with a column of STUDENTID I need to pull all data for. There are 2000 STUDENTID values in EXCEL file and are subject to change. Thus I am wondering, can I execute a command such as

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE STUDENTID IN (EXCEL FILE)`....

or must I list all STUDENTID value in the QUERY? It is on DATAGRIPS.

Comment: You can't directly do this, but you can load the data into another table using something like `LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/excel_file.csv' INTO TABLE students` and then do a join on the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of free and paid Excel JDBC drivers [1](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/excelonline/jdbc/), [2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xlsql/), [3](https://github.com/rondunn/JDBCExcel) on the market that can be used within DataGrip via [user driver functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/other-databases.html#using-user-driver-files).